# C Can't read the last property in struct properly

Tags: c

I'm having trouble getting the last property in a struct.

This is my struct

```
#define MAX_FILE_NUM 64
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 15

typedef struct 
{
    char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH]; //file name
    int size; //size of the file
    int used; //0 represents the file is not used and 1 represents the file is used
    int block; //the index of data block that stores the file
    int block_count; //the number of blocks the file used
    int file_descriptor_count; //the number of file descriptors are referring to the file
}file_detail;
```

Assuming the code update the directory info at i = 0

```
file_detail * directory_block_ptr = (file_detail *)malloc(4096);

int create(char *name){
    if(name == NULL || find_file(name) != -1 || strlen(name) > MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH || super_block_ptr->files >= MAX_FILE_NUM){
        printf("%s\n", "ERROR: file create condition not satified");
        return -1;
    }

    //create the file
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_NUM; i++){
        //update directory info
        if((directory_block_ptr+i)->used == 0){
            strcpy((directory_block_ptr+i)->file_name, name);
            (directory_block_ptr+i)->size = 0;
            (directory_block_ptr+i)->file_descriptor_count = 0;
            (directory_block_ptr+i)->used = 1;
            (directory_block_ptr+i)->block = -1;
            (directory_block_ptr+i)->block_count = 0;
            printf("%d\n", (directory_block_ptr+i)->file_descriptor_count);//correct output 0   
            break;
        }
    }


    printf("%d\n", (directory_block_ptr+0)->file_descriptor_count);//incorrect output
    //open the file
    int result = fs_open(name);

    if(result != -1)
    {
        printf("%s: %s %s\n", "File", name,  "created successfully");
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

But when I'm trying to access the file_decsriptor_count outside of the for loop, I get random numbers like 1868958256.

```
create("test");
```

Comment: That number translates to hex 0x6F660A30, which translates to ASCII characters `"of\n0"` (could be the other way around); any chance the `file_name` buffer is getting overflowed by a too-long name?

Comment: print your filename lengths

Comment: How is `directory_block_ptr` defined and how is the memory for it alllocated? Please update the code with definitions of `MAX_FILE_NUM` `MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH`.

Comment: The newline suggests the file name was obtained with `fgets` and the trailing newline is still present. The question needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem.

Comment: Re the edit: `#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 15` is rubbish. What happens when you print the other `struct` members?

Comment: @WeatherVane why so? Please explain.

Comment: Too short for practical purposes. Try a much longer string until the code is working.

Comment: @WeatherVane other members are giving me the expected numbers.

Comment: @WeatherVane well this is the requirement. So do you have a reason of calling it rubbish?

Comment: @desperatecoder - if we can't see all the code, we can't tell what the not-seen parts are doing, and this is important.  What `name` is being entered here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to be disrespectful, just that such a short filename could cause problems. You posted more sections of code, but still the question does need [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be copy/pasted, compiled and run to reproduce the problem. One advanantage  to you in preparing that, can be you find the problem along the way.

Comment: name is passed in as "test".

Comment: I notice the test `strlen(name) > MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH`, however either this test, or the member `char file_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];` is off by 1. The value returned by `strlen` excludes the nul terminator, but the string's length must allow for it.

Comment: @WeatherVane after taking account of nil terminator, is this better: strlen(name)+1 > MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH

Comment: That is better.

Comment: @WeatherVane you're better lol ;)

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions. but I still can't get the expected number.

Comment: Then most probably the error is somewhere else, not in the code you showed.

Comment: Are we certain that `directory_block_ptr[0]` is actually even being initialized? One thing to try: at the very bottom of each `for` loop, add: `printf("in loop %d, fdcount[0] = %d\n", (directory_block_ptr+0)->file_descriptor_count);`  This is the generally unproductive but widely used "printf debugging", see at which point it goes off the rails.   Alternately, in the existing printf in the loop it should identify the index so the "correct output" is known to be correct **for the proper index**

Comment: Come to think about it: how is `directory_block_ptr` initialized? The memory from `malloc()` is generally random, and if you're assuming that `directory_block_ptr[x]->used` is zero automatically, that would be surprising.  Perhaps, right after your `malloc()` you do `memset(directory_block_ptr, 0, 4096);` to insure that the whole memory chunk is zeroed out. `calloc()` could be used as well.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use array syntax to address your array? `(directory_block_ptr+i)->size` could be shorter and better readable: `directory_block_ptr[i].size`

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh I didn't know I can use that. Thank you!

Comment: Please do not destroy the question by deleting all the relevant content.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and propose that the memory from `malloc` is uninitialized, and that's what's going on here.

In the loop (and rewriting into proper array format as suggested by @Gerhardh):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_NUM; i++) {
        //update directory info
        if( directory_block_ptr[i].used == 0) {
            // assign stuff
            printf("%d\n", directory_block_ptr[i].file_descriptor_count);//correct output 0   
            break;
        }
    }
```

The OP says they get the correct value, but we don't know that it's the `[0]` index, right? If there's junk in position `directory_block_ptr[0].used`, then that position will not be touched and the loop will move onto the next one. We just don't know which one is being found.

Recommend to OP: change the `printf` in the loop to be:

```
printf("%d set in position [%d]\n", directory_block_ptr[i].file_descriptor_count, i);
```

and see if it's telling you position `[0]` or `[1]` or whatever. My guess is not-zero.

Recommend to OP, change your initialization at the top to be:

```
#define DIRECTORY_BLOCK_SIZE  4096

file_detail *directory_block_ptr = malloc(DIRECTORY_BLOCK_SIZE);

memset(directory_block_ptr, 0, DIRECTORY_BLOCK_SIZE);
```

This allocates the same amount of memory, but insures that it's all set to zero, then run it again.

Also, this is more a matter of style than of substance, I'd do the loop this way by defining a much simpler variable name for access throughout the loop, it's easier to follow.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_NUM; i++){
        file_detail *fd = &(directory_block_ptr[i]); // shorthand

        //update directory info
        if(fd->used == 0){
            strcpy(fd->file_name, name);
            fd->size = 0;
            fd->file_descriptor_count = 0;
            fd->used = 1;
            fd->block = -1;
            fd->block_count = 0;
            printf("%d set in position [%d]\n", fd->file_descriptor_count, i);
            break;
        }
    }
```